# How to Extract only numbers from the String without using function in SQL

Tags: sql, replace, numeric

Table contains data as below

Table Name is REGISTER

Column Name is EXAM_CODE

Values like ('S6TJ','S7','S26','S24')

I want answer like below

Result set - > (6,7,26,24)

Please suggest solution - since regexp_replace is not recognized built in function name in SQL.

Comment: Are the numbers always grouped together?  So you can have `S6TJ` = `6` but not `S6JT4` = `64`?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: It can contain data like S6TJ or S6JT4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity of the answer depends on two things: the RDBMS used and whether the numbers in the `EXAM_CODE` are contiguous.

I have assumed that the RDBMS is SQL Server and the numbers in `EXAM_CODE` are always contiguous.  If not, please advise and I can revise the answer.

The following SQL shows a way of accomplishing the above using `PATINDEX`.:

```
CREATE TABLE #REGISTER (EXAM_CODE VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO #REGISTER VALUES ('S6TJ'),('S7'),('S26'),('S24');

SELECT  LEFT(EXAM_CODE, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', EXAM_CODE) - 1)
  FROM  (
        SELECT  RIGHT(EXAM_CODE, LEN(EXAM_CODE) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', EXAM_CODE) + 1) + 'A' AS EXAM_CODE
          FROM  #REGISTER
        ) a

DROP TABLE #REGISTER
```

This outputs:

```
6
7
26
24
```

`PATINDEX` matches a specified pattern against a string (or returns 0 if there is no match).

Using this, the inner query fetches all of the string AFTER the first occurence of a number.  The outer query then strips any text that may appear on the end of the string.

Note: The character `A` is appended to the result of the inner query in order to ensure that the `PATINDEX` check in the outer query will make a match.  Otherwise, `PATINDEX` would return 0 and an error would occur.

Comment: @Ram Glad to help. Could you please ensure to mark this as the correct answer then?